# Напишите программу, которая генерирует список из N элементов в диапазоне от 1 до 10

Tags: python

Вывести список на экран. Удалить из списка все
элементы, кратные значению k или m (k и m ввести с клавиатуры).
Например, удалить все числа, кратные 3 или 5.

Проблема только в условии к списку:
Не понимаю, как задать диапазон

```
l = [list for i in range (n)]
print (l)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно именно через генератор списка, тогда можно так:

`[random.randint(1,10) for i in range(n)]`

Предполагается, что нужно сгенерировать список **случайных** значений в диапазоне от 1 до 10 включительно, n — длина списка.